# Manifest v2 is being deprecated while Google ask Google Identity Services to be used on Manifest v2 only

Tags: google-identity, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

First thanks to all SO members for growing the coder inside me that I am able to articulate my thoughts only after doing some homework on my own.

Query: This seems like a contradictory statement from Google. In Identity Platform related Documentation, Google asks you to use Manifest V2 as V3 does not support Identity Services. So I decided to use switch to V2 to my Chrome Extension which I was earlier build and published as V3. But then got error when tried to run Unpacked Extension:

[image]

and this is what official documentation asking to degrade to V2:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/chrome-extension

> Important: Identity Platform supports only extensions that use Manifest V2. Manifest V3 isn't supported because it doesn't provide pop-up operations.

Update : adding Manifest v3:

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "hirall",
  "description": "Getting Profiles for Insight",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "homepage_url":
    "https://www.example.com",
  "author": "example",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "storage"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src 'self';"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["hit.js"],
      "css": ["assets/style.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon-16.png",
    "48": "assets/icon-48.png",
    "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "result.html",
    "default_icon": "assets/icon-16.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like something you should be asking Google Support about, rather than asking here.

Comment: The deprecation is a warning, not an error, so you can still use ManifestV2. The error is different: "reading onClicked", which you should fix by replacing `action` with `browserAction` in the background script and `browser_action` in manifest.json. The host permissions should be moved to `permissions`, and `scripting` should be removed and its calls replaced with chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: My Understanding is that They will not let it publish if it is in V2 as stated here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/mv2-sunset/

I guess I should rope Google for this